# Determine at runtime whether the "Visual Studio Hosting Process" is enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

In **C#** or **VB.Net**, how I could determine whether the **Visual Studio Hosting Process** debugging feature is enabled on my running application?

[image]

Comment: A better question is "why do you need to know"? While the runtime environment is slightly different, it seems to me like you would want to know exactly *what* differences are in place that you need to know about, rather than that it happens to be the Visual Studio hosting process that's causing them.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Is for testing purpposes around a LL mouse hook that I'm developing, since it requires VSHostProcess to be disabled to run then I would like to detect if the VSHostProcess debugger is attached or not during the debugging of my app in an automated and efficient way of course.

Comment: If your application can't run correctly at all without the mouse hook, is it an option to detect if the hook was installed correctly and if not, signal an error, possibly including a helpful hint like "if you are running this under the Visual Studio hosting process, don't"? Realistically, though, because this option is part of the project configuration, it should be enough to set this correctly once and check it in. People who change it back have themselves to blame.

Comment: How does the hosting process prevent your mouse hook from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c#: `if (Debugger.IsAttached = true)`

vb: `If Debugger.IsAttached Then`

edit: ignore that bit above, I misunderstood, try this:

`if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.EndsWith("vshost.exe"))`

or another:

`if (Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName.Contains("mscorlib"))`

but yes, if you then named your assembly mscorlib you might run into problems...

Comment: I guess that's not what `Debugger.IsAttached` mean. It simply means that whether any debugger is attached to your process. It could be native debugger.

Comment: thanks for answer but a look inside the debugger class was the first that I tried... As I've read the VS Hosting process is not a debugger at all but it adds some debugging features, then your code suggestion does not take effect.

Comment: And what will happens if for any reason my assembly filename contains "vshost" string?... an string comparison on the app filename is not really what I'm looking for due to its inefficiency, I wonder that exists a better way to determine it, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: your first concern is easily addressed: don't do that, then. Why would anyone deliberately stick `vshost` in the name somewhere (other than to trip you up)? Your second concern baffles me -- there is nothing inefficient about checking a string for a particular ending, particularly not because you only have to do this once and store it in a `static boolean` field (as the name will never change at runtime).

Comment: If you start digging into it further, it gets even more weird. If I start a debugging session with the Visual Studio Hosting process enabled, I get two behaviors, both absurd and potentially hazardous.

Comment: If you start digging into it further, it gets even more weird. If I start a debugging session with the Visual Studio Hosting process enabled, I get two behaviors, both absurd and potentially hazardous. First, if you call System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly, the Visual Studio Hosting Process assembly is reflected to you.. Along the same lines, if you query System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess ( ).MainModule.FileName, you get the same thing. Worse yet is that if you use that filename to query the subsystem ID (in the PE header), you are informed that the subsystem ID is 2.

Comment: If your console program expects that query to return 3, and your program makes decisions based on on the subsystem type, it will misbehave. Worse yet, queries for the version resources return them from the VS host, NOT your program!

Comment: The strangest thing of all, however, is that an enumeration of the modules loaded into the process lists the hosting process, but the console program is nowhere to be found!